# What are some of the observable effects of black holes

Tags: astronomy

Is there some kind of observation of a black hole (or a black hole candidate) which could be made from earth, and which might be able to distinguish between two Black Hole models? (1) the classical model with an event horizon and an internal singular point of infinite density and (2) the so-called Fuzzball model which is now being written about.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168536/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29696/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409/

Comment: Garabed, see [The Formation and Growth of Black holes](http://mathpages.com/rr/s7-02/7-02.htm) where you can read about a classical model which doesn't have an internal singular point of infinite density. There's misrepresentation going on in popscience articles like [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2015/06/fuzzball-fix-black-hole-paradox/), wherein string theorists promote  themselves to an unsuspecting public who don't realise that's there's no evidence whatsoever to support their speculations. Next time you hear about something like this, ask this question: _what are the strings made out of?_