# Corona Discharge by black holes

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics

NASA has published pictures showing corona discharge from a black hole. But how is it possible and  if so how does this corona discharge happen. Please explain

Comment: So... you don't have a link to these pictures? Or you don't want to include it?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137837/25301

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you are referring to [this observation of a flare from a black hole](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=4753).

[image: Corona flare]

(image is from the linked article and is an artists rendering of the flare)

The answer is that the X-rays are being generated by the hot gas falling into the black hole, not from within the black hole itself (which is of course impossible).

However the physics that controls how these flares evolve is not well understood. It remains an active area of study.

Comment: Clarification for the public: the image is an artist's rendering, not a literal photo of an observation, but is based on actual telescope data.

Comment: @Asher: good point, thanks. If you want to edit in changes like that I'm always happy for people to make that sort of change.

Comment: thank you for the invitation. I post from the mobile app most days and haven't figured out how to initiate an edit within the app.

Comment: Wait never mind, it's right there at the bottom of the answer... that's what I get for not paying attention.