# Why can people take a picture of black hole which absorb all light?

Tags: black-holes

Who can tell me why the bright area of black hole is asymmetrical and exist below ?

Comment: Why the downvote(s)?

Comment: take a look at this video, it's pretty well explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyH3XhpLTo

Comment: Probably related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137837/25301

Comment: What do you mean by "and exist below" here?

Comment: Maybe my description is improper, as the picture shows, the bright area is distributed below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a picture of the black hole; it's a picture of the *shadow* of the black hole.  The black hole itself is surrounded by a disc of gas that is so hot it's glowing — which we assume is because the black hole is pulling on the disc so hard that its particles must be going really fast to be able to stay outside of the black hole, which means that any collisions are really energetic and heat up the gas like crazy.  And the light from that glowing disc is what the picture is showing.  But before the light gets to us, it gets warped by the black hole, and some of it gets swallowed up by the black hole.  Some of the disc is apparently closer to us, and therefore not blocked — and [partially warped by the black-hole's spin](https://doi.org/10.3847/2041-8213/ab0f43).

Comment: Why is the gas not falling into the black hole?

Comment: @ShuvoSarker Angular momentum — the same reason the Earth doesn't crash into the Sun, and Saturn's rings don't crash into Saturn.  The disc is orbiting at [up to ~1,000$\,\mathrm{km/s}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87#Supermassive_black_hole), so even though this supermassive black hole at the center is pulling on the gas very hard, the gas is orbiting so quickly that it  (mostly) just stays in orbit.